# How to "reset" the UISearchBar when back from another view showing the search results?

Tags: ios, swift, controls, uisearchbar

My 1st view has only `UISearchBar`, it will go to 2nd view to show the search results. When I click "back" button on the 2nd view, it come back to the 1st view with `UISearchBar`. I can use either `UINavigation` Controller or Segue to back to 1st view.

My question is how do I "reset" or "control" the SearchBar when it comes back to the 1st view? E.g., how do you "remove" the search-keywords which still left at the SearchBar, and also display the cursor inside the SearchBar?

[image]

Comment: Which type you using for show the result `UIView` or `UIViewController` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you return to the **First ViewController** you can do `yourSearchBar.text = ""` to clear `UISearchBar`'s text and `yourSearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` to get keyboard up again.
You can put this code to **First ViewController**'s `viewWillApear` or to your unwind segue.

For detailed answer please add a code snippet...

Comment: It works, but added a "blank" view a fraction sec before showing 1st view.

Comment: Do you use storyboard? or just code? How do you go to your second ViewController? Please show me your code..

Comment: I use storyboard + code, 1st viewcontroller embedded in navigation controller. the code in 1st viewcontroller "if result.count != 0 {

                        let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "2ndViewController") as! 2ndViewController
       
                        destinationController.searchResultTitle =  searchKeyWords

                        destinationController.searchResultList = result                 
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController, animated: true)

Comment: I found out it's dismissed the 2nd view, then showed a fraction sec of  "blank view" (actually from 2nd view background image), then loaded the 1st view. Thanks!

Comment: the 2nd viecontroller: override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

Comment: Why `popToRootViewController` is in `viewDidDisappear`? You don't need to add `popToRootViewController` in  `viewDidDisappear`..

Comment: And the 'Keyboard showing up at first' is because of  `viewWillAppear`. So if you not want to show keyboard up at first, you have to put `yourSearchBar.text = ""` and `yourSearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` to your secondVC's `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: like.. `let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!; let firstVC = window.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0] as! FirstViewContoller; firstVC.yourSearchBar.text = ""; firstVC.yourSearchBar.becomeFirstResponder();` or you can use **Delegate**...

Answer (score 0):

When your UIViewController appear at the time `viewWillAppear` method will execute. Then put the reset code there.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    youSearchBar.text = ""
    youSearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned to Daniel, it added a "blank" view before showing my 1st view, also changes the 1st view behavior after launching the app, the search icon was not in the middle of the search bar as the initial status, it's on the left and keyboard shows up.